# How do you encrypt only a part of a whole file (example: first 2500 bytes only) in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I'm working on a node app that encrypts and decrypts files using crypto. But right now I'm trying to encrypt only a specific n size of a file. For example, I only want to encrypt the first 2500 bytes of a file, then write the buffer again to the disk (The first 2500 bytes are encrypted and the rest is as is)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is your intended end result a file with the first 2500 bytes encrypted and the rest as-is?

Comment: Hi! Yes exactly! (also edited the question)

Comment: Slice the problem up into smaller problems and tackle them one by one. Is it necessary to know whether you're encrypting the first 2500 bytes or not? Do you have an issue of copying a file by reading and writing bytes instead of using existing APIs to copy files? Do you have trouble with the actual encryption step or did you already figure it out? If you plan to do it in-place then this gets really complicated.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. I'm planning to do it in-place and now it gets really complicated because the encrypted data is a little bit bigger than the original data so when I try to write it back to the file, it overwrites other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're encrypting the data, but it's not important here.

The key idea is to just read the first 2500 bytes of the file, and then write those bytes back (encrypted) using the `r+` flag for `fs.createWriteStream`. Specifically, `fs.createWriteStream(file, {start: 0, flags: 'r+'})` will start writing at the beginning of the file. Simply write the 2500 encrypted bytes to the file stream and you're done.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Accepted the answer. Thanks Mate!!

Comment: Just a quick update, I'm having problems with writing it back to the file stream. It's because the encrypted bytes is much longer than the original one. I'm currently using aes128. So right now I'm finding a solution how to write it back without overwriting the other data. I used createWriteStream but it basically overwrites the other data.

Comment: Yes, that's bound to be an issue. You'll need some sort of encryption method that outputs the same length as the input.

Comment: Hi Matt! An update, already resolved the length issue. I used CTR mode on my algorithm (aes128/256). Thanks for the help!